# Widget.AppCompat.TextView not found after Migrate to material design

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, material-components-android

I've just migrated to material design 1.2.1 but i have some issues when building the application.

I've replaced all <TextView objects with <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView> and still have build issues.

> The error is: AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView
> (aka com.app.package:style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView) not found.

Note this are some of mine dependencies versions:
Also keep in mind that before replace the appcompat library with material i've migrated to androidX using Studio plugin, also only with material 1.0.0 i don't have build problems.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that i've tried normal things like clean/rebuild invalidate cache and restart, but this not help me

Comment: try to delete build folder that might work.

Comment: @pallavirichhariya i've tried the result is the same :(

Comment: try to make compile sdk version 21 in app  build.gradle

Comment: check `style` xml file, maybe there old lines of a  `AppCompat.TextView`

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem, which I could not solve until I removed this block of code from the application module build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.appcompat') {
                details.useVersion "1.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code was intended to replace the AppCompat library version in all included dependencies with 1.0.2 vesrion (this was workaround to solve some problems with WebView). Perhaps you also had a script that replaces the version for appcompat.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue via:

- Update all **androidx** libraries to the latest version.
- Remove all dependencies like **com.android.support:appcompat***
- Replace all TextView with AppCompatTextView ot MaterialTextView
- Update to the latest buildTools and Gradle plugin